How can i see 'engine.options' values?
Using stockfish engine with python, i can use the bellow code to set an option:
import chess.engine

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("/usr/bin/stockfish")

# Set an option.
engine.configure({"Hash": 32})
 

But when I print the option I just configured, no field relating to the current value appears:
print(engine.options["Hash"])
#Result: "Option(name='Hash', type='spin', default=16, min=1, max=131072, var=[])"

